# Unable to wait for async call in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a call to AWS where I get a response and the callback looks like so:

```
const handleResponse = async (response) => {
  var responseBody = "";
  response.on("data", async function (chunk) {
    responseBody += chunk;
  });
  response.on("end", async function (chunk) {
    return responseBody;
  });
  return responseBody;
};
```

My current attempt is to call this function with an await like such:

```
const getLoadIds = async (payload) => {
  //   console.log(payload);
  const resp = await handleResponse(payload)
  console.log(resp) <--- this is undefined
}
```

How can I get the response from the response.on("end") call?

Here is the original caller code:

```
  var client = new AWS.HttpClient();
  try {
    await client.handleRequest(request, null, async (res) => fn(res));
  } catch (err) {
```

`fn` is an alias to `getLoadIds`

Comment: `handleResponse` is not doing anything asynchronously... It just immediately returns the empty string.

Comment: That is because you are returning right away from `handleResponse`. To do this, remove async from the function, then return a promise instead from `handleResponse` that resolves to `responseBody` when the `end` event occurs. Remove async from your callbacks.

Comment: @AndrewLi Do you mind posting an example of this flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have something like

```
const handleResponse = (response) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var responseBody = "";
    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
      responseBody += chunk;
    });
    response.on("end", function (chunk) {
      resolve(responseBody);
    });
  });
};
```

upd: thanx @Andrew Li, noticed bug issue in the answer

Comment: Don't forget error handling though

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the stream handler in a promise. `resolve` it if returns data, and `reject` if it has an error.

```
function handleResponse() {
  let responseBody = '';
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    response.on('data', (chunk) => responseBody += chunk);
    response.on('end', () => res(responseBody));
    response.on('error', (error) => rej(error));
  });
};

function getLoadIds(payload) {
  const resp = await handleResponse(payload);
  console.log(resp);
}
```